# Clean way of combining an array for a listbox

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

Most of the listboxes I use, make use of the lists function i.e.

```
->lists('id', 'name')
```

Is there a nice simple function for doing the same thing but also joins strings together? something like...

```
->lists('id', 'name'.' - '.'description')
```

I have a function that does this already, but it has to run through the database and make many queries before joining everything together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an accessor in your model

```
public function getNameDescriptionAttribute($value)
{
    return "$this->name - $this->description";
}
```

then when querying

```
->get()->lists('id', 'name_description')
```

Make sure you `get()` before listing.

Comment: You don't need to `get()` before you  `lists()`.

Comment: You do need the the extra get() in this case!